# Print the sourced R file to an appendix using Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

I keep R and Rnw files separate, then load the R data/plots with `load("file.R")` in the first Sweave chunk. Is there a way that I can print the sourced R file to an appendix without executing all of the code? (i.e., the code is slow enough that I don't want to `source()` it in an `echo=TRUE` chunk).

Thanks!

---

Update -- actually, I don't think my `source()` idea works.

Comment: Wouldn't you like to, say, just print the R script file into the Rnw file?

Comment: @aL3xa -- Yeah, that's probably a better way to say it! :). But I want to put it at the end. When I first started Sweaving, I would but all the calcs into the first chunk, and then you could echo it all, but I would like (1) for it to go at the end and (2) not have to execute on each compile when I'm working on the typesetting. I tried `print("file.R")` in a chunk with various settings, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Well, in that case, you don't need any of R/Sweave functionality. Besides, @newuser already got it! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using a Latex package?
Add into your header
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
Then
\VerbatimInput{yourRfile.R}

Comment: @newuser -- Thanks for the pointer, I was on the wrong path. I found that the listings package worked a little better for me (I wanted line wrap and couldn't figure out how to do it with fancyvrb. For posterity, here's what I'm using: `\usepackage{listings} \usepackage{courier} \lstset{breaklines=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily}`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `highlight` package to output nicely formatted, colorful code:

```
highlight("myRfile.R", renderer = renderer_latex(document = F))
```

But don't forget to put in your latex doc the lengthy preamble which you get with document=T.

You can experiment with code directly:

```
highlight(output="test.tex", 
          parser.output = parser(text = deparse(lm)),
          renderer =  renderer_latex(document = T))
```

And get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I usually solve this by:

```
\begin{appendix}

\section{Appendix A}

\subsection{R session information}

<<SessionInforamtaion,echo=F,eval=T,results=tex>>=

toLatex(sessionInfo())

@


\subsection{The simulation's source code}

<<SourceCode,echo=F,eval=T>>=

Stangle(file.path("Projectpath","RnwFile.Rnw"))

SourceCode <- readLines(file.path("Projectpath","Codefile.R"))

writeLines(SourceCode)

@
\end{appendix}
```

Using this you have to think of a maximum numbers of characters per line.

Answer (score 2):

Separating R and Rnw files sort of defeats the purpose of literate programming. My own approach is to include the code chunks at the appropriate place in the text. If my audience isn't interested in the code, then I might mark it as

```
<<foo, echo=FALSE>>=
x <- 1:10
@
```

I might assemble the code in an appendix as

```
<<appendix-foo, eval=FALSE>>=
<<foo>>
@
```

which I admit is a bit of a kludge and error prone (forgotten chunks). One quickly wants to bundle the document with supporting material (data sets, useful helper functions, non-R scripts) into an R package, and these are not difficult to create. Building the package automatically creates the pdf and Stangle'd R file, which is exactly what you want. Package building can be a slow process, but installing the package does not require that the vignettes be rebuilt and so is fast and convenient for whomever you're giving the package to.

For twiddling with formatting / text, I use a global option `\SweaveOpts{eval=FALSE}`.

Comment: +1! That's a great trick! But for lengthy calculations (1000+ lines of code) that can take a while to run (measured in minutes or hours), do you think that I should combine calculations and type-setting into one file? I know there are tools like cachesweave, but I've had much better luck keeping the two separate and letting them use the same workspace and saving the workspace and sourcing if later I need to tweak typesetting. Or in the case of the OP, I want to append the entire code, I can easily do so.

Comment: As well, the code typically predates the typsetting by a few months... although that's a process that could use a lot of improvement :).

Comment: For me, 1000 lines of code would end up as bite-sized functions in a package, documented as 'man' pages and with unit tests to ensure functionality. And then yes, the analysis (a series of calls to the functions) would be an Sweave vignette that took a long time to process. I might use tricks along the way to cache objects, but the final version would be tightly coupled to the actual code. A more 'literate' approach would present the functions as Sweave / no-web; a recent example is the R [compiler](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/compiler/) but this is the work of a true wizard.