# how to produce a sweave document without angle bracket ">" in front of code chunks?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

How can I produce a Sweave (or pgfSweave) document without angle brackets ">" in front of code chunks? I want people to be able to cut and paste my code directly from the pdf output. Here's a snippet of my document with a code chunk:

Notice that because our incidence matrix consists of 0’s and 1’s, the off-diagonal entries represent the total number of common columns, which is exactly what we wanted. We’ll use the %*% operator to tell R to do this. Let’s first take a look at a small example using toy data of people and groups to which they belong. We’ll coerce the data to an incidence matrix using the table() function, then multiply the incidence matrix by its transpose to get the number of common groups between people.

```
>\> ToyDat <- data.frame(person = c("Sam", "Sam", "Sam", "Greg", "Tom", "Tom"), group = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), stringsAsFactors = F)
>\> ToyDatM <- as.matrix(table(ToyDat)) 
>\> ToyDatM
```

But I want the code to look like:

```
> ToyDat <- data.frame(person = c("Sam", "Sam", "Sam", "Greg", "Tom", "Tom"), group = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), stringsAsFactors = F)    
> ToyDatM <- as.matrix(table(ToyDat)) 
> ToyDatM
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think `options(prompt = " ")` at the top of your script will do it.

`prompt` (in `options()`) controls the text string used for the prompt in an interactive session and I'm assuming it will do the same for a document processed through Sweave.

EDIT: Thanks to Ben Bolker for pointing out that `options(prompt = " ", continue = " ")` will also take care of the "+" problem as well.

Comment: Yes, it does.  You'll probably want to do the options command in its own chunk before you do anything else and mark it with `echo=FALSE`.

Comment: I suggest `options(prompt=" ",continue=" ")` to shut off the `+` continuation character too ... (I almost always use the latter in my Sweave documents now)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a better strategy is to provide the result of `Stangle` on your Rnw file -- it'll contain the commands from the entire document, as a script that can be submitted to R or cut-and-paste into an R session.

Comment: For an example, see Hans's answer to this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362747/print-the-sourced-r-file-to-an-appendix-using-sweave/5976333#5976333

Comment: Actually, for a 'simple' document I'd rather `Stangle("Simple.Rnw")` as an additional step in the work flow I was using to make the pdf. But in practice my Sweave documents always end up in a package (inst/doc/Simple.Rnw in R-2.13, vignettes/Simple.Rnw in devel) and then the pdf and .R files are created on package installation (and are at `system.file("doc", package="MyPackage")` -- I get to bundle data and other artifacts with my document, and don't have to re-invent infrastructure for processing documents. Packages aren't that hard to make.

Comment: Meant to say that pdf and R files are created on package build, which means that the package creator bears the brunt of the expensive part (creating the vignette, which also requires a functioning latex) whereas whomever is using the package just has to install it, without additional software dependencies.