# Sweave control of chuk output

Tags: r, sweave

I'm using Sweave to make a report in R-Studio, and I have the problem, that my teacher will only accept reports, where the code is placed in an Appendix. This means that I need to control the position of the chunk outputs (graphs).

Is this possible in Sweave?

Regards,

Jens

Comment: Can you provide [a minimal reproducible exmaple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show your intended output? This should be possible by referencing chunks and controlling output, but it's hard to say exactly without more information.

Comment: Maybe this could help? [Appendix at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362747/print-the-sourced-r-file-to-an-appendix-using-sweave)

Answer (score 0):

This will return everything in your code. Using the \usepackage{fancyvrb} and the \VerbatimInput{test.Rnw} assuming that your file is named test.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<my_code_chunk>>=
2+2
@

\section{Appendix}
\VerbatimInput{test.Rnw}

\end{document}
```

Here is another example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
<<my_code_chunk>>=
2+2
@
\section{Appendix}

<<>>=
<<my_code_chunk>>
@

\end{document}
```