# R Sweave: put the whole code of the .Rnw file in Appendix?

Tags: r, sweave

I just found this [awesome technique](https://yihui.name/en/2018/09/code-appendix/) to put the code used in the .Rmd file in the appendix (of that same file).

However, I am using R Sweave and not R Markdown and I would like to know if there exists a similar way to put all the code at the end in a unique chunk. The code to do that in Markdown does not work in Sweave. I precise that, unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362747/print-the-sourced-r-file-to-an-appendix-using-sweave), I do not have a separate .R file where the calculations are made. Everything is done in the .Rnw file.

Does anybody know how to do it?

**Edit** : a reproducible example

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<reg2, echo=FALSE, print=FALSE>>=
head(mtcars)
@

<<reg3, echo=FALSE, print=FALSE>>=
head(iris)
@

\section*{Appendix}
% the place where I could like to put the whole code

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you really using `Sweave()`, or `knitr` with Sweave-like inputs?  Including a small reproducible example would tell us.

Comment: yes I'm using sweave and not just ```knitr``` with latex inputs, I added a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chunk works to include the code:

```
<<echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE>>=
filename <- tempfile(fileext=".R")
Stangle("test.Rnw", output = filename, quiet = TRUE)
cat(readLines(filename), sep = "\n")
@
```

When I include that in your example file, I see this:

[image: screenshot]

I think it's possible to modify the format a bit; see `?Rtangle` for some details.  Similar things are possible with `knitr`, but it's more flexible.  I suspect the best method would be similar to the one you found for RMarkdown.

Comment: that works great, I will keep trying to adapt the working code I found for R Markdown to Sweave but at least, this is an option to provide the necessary code in the pdf, thanks a lot :)